# How to extract GIT logs using windows batch

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, logging, extract

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set GitPath="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\"
set NamFile="test.txt"
set /A DatExpo=0
set OutMesg=""

call %GitPath%git.exe log > %NamFile%

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('type "%NamFile%"') do (

  set x=%%i
  echo 1: DatExpo is %DatExpo% >> aaa.txt
  echo 1: Compare /!x:~0,5!/ and /Date:/ >> aaa.txt
  if "!x:~0,5!"=="Date:" (
    set /A DatExpo=%DatExpo%+1
  )

  echo 2: DatExpo is %DatExpo% >> aaa.txt
  if "!x:~0,6!"=="commit" (
    if %DatExpo%==1 (
      goto :outBreak
    )
  )

)

:outBreak
```

I am trying to extract the date and the log message from a GIT logs as follows:

```
commit c0a3377e5144c37bb3cadd93ef68167ef3097703
Author: ------------------------------------
Date:   Thu Jun 14 17:40:27 2018 +0300

    Relocated: File line golden retriever ( who's a good boy )

commit 42339bbdce74a76889d46714de09ed7b0bf8b955
Author: ------------------------------------
Date:   Tue Jun 12 13:05:38 2018 +0300

    Added: Feature A
```

The BAT file must return:

```
Date:   Thu Jun 14 17:40:27 2018 +0300
Relocated: File line golden retriever ( who's a good boy )
```

I am having the following in the file `aaa.txt` :

```
1: DatExpo is 0 
1: Compare /Date:/ and /Date:/ 
2: DatExpo is 0 
1: DatExpo is 0
```

What gives and why the variable is not set and the two strings compared ?!

Comment: Why are you using the `Call` command for `git.exe`? It should not be necessary, try removing it! Also within your loop you should be using `!DatExpo!` instead of `%DatExpo%`.

Comment: I am calling git.exe to generate the log file and stream it to `test.txt`

Comment: I'm informing you about the use of the `Call` command, not that of `git.exe`, did you try removing it? _It would have been quicker than typing and posting your comment in response._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced all % with ! and now works !

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set GitPath="C:\Program Files\Git\bin\"
set NamFile="test.txt"
set /A DatExpo=0
set OutMesg="out.txt"

del OutMesg

call !GitPath!git.exe log > !NamFile!

for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('type "!NamFile!"') do (
  set x=%%i
  if "!x:~0,5!"=="Date:" (
    set /A DatExpo=!DatExpo!+1
  )
  if "!x:~0,6!"=="commit" (
    if !DatExpo!==1 (
      goto :outBreak
    )
  )
  if "!DatExpo!"=="1" (
    echo !x! >> !OutMesg!
  )
)

echo OutMesg

:outBreak
```

Comment: If you noted my comment, I told you that the problem was the instances of `%DatExpo%` in the loop; `%GitPath%`, `%NamFile%` and `%OutMesg%` were perfectly fine as they were, because their values were not changed within the loop or any code block. Additionally the recommended way to `Set` variables is `Set "Variable=Value"`, not `Set Variable="Value"`, when you use that variable, you doublequote it as necessary during that usage, e.g. `"%GitPath%git.exe"`.